# Child selector with .has() method not working

Tags: jquery

(General question was indeed already asked, but the answer given here gives a nice way to solve the problem posed here, instead of the other question's 'behind the scenes' explanation...)

I'm trying to highlight all the cells in a table (with embedded tables) that contains an input field.

Sample code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaARY/)

I can do it with `$('#rec td:has(>input)')` but I would prefer to use the [.has() method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) as the doc for the [:has() selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) mentions performance issues - my table can become quite big with several embedded tables and I - still - have to support IE6...

However, `$('#rec td').has('>input')` does not work (it includes cells which does not actually have an `<input>` as a direct child), seemingly ignoring the `>` child selector...

Is there a way to get the same result with the .has() method as with the :has() selector?

Comment: There are no `<` in my JavaScript...

Comment: Yea I meant `>`. This was not the only problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it will be more efficient to find all `input`'s first, then their parent `td`'s:

```
$('#rec input').closest('td').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

This way it shall not be needed to inspect every table cell and its children.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zaARY/5/)**

Comment: Ah...  Reverse logic!  I keep forgetting that it's sometimes best to attack the problem from the other side.  :-)  Thanks

Comment: Ended up using `$('#rec input').parent('td')` to limit the element returned to the direct parent of the `input` (`closest` will keep going through ancestors until it find a `td`).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing > from the .has()

Comment: .has() "Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element."  It does not return bool.
.filter() "Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function’s test."  It does not do what I want here.

Comment: Following change in answer: Removing the `>` from the `.has()` actually works as I would expect it - it includes TDs which doesn't have an input as a direct child, hence the need for the `>`.  That's why I said that `.has()` seems to ignore the `>`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rec td').has('input').addClass('highlight')
```

or

```
$.each($('#rec td').has('input'), function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: `.has()` will check all descendants of an element, I want to only check direct children of the element.  That's why I tried adding the `>` which seems to be ignored.